# Why does changing the salt of the salt bridge effect the voltage produced in a galvanic cell?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, electrochemistry, redox, solutions

My experiments results showed that the voltage decreases down $\pu{Group 1}$: $\ce{Cl-}$ salts in the salt bridge. All other variables were kept constant. $\ce{Zn}$ and $\ce{Cu}$ rods were used. Concentrations of the salt in the salt bridge were $\pu{1M}$.

I dont understand this result. What could the reason be behind this?

Comment: The voltage measured in a Zn/Cu cell does not depend on the nature of the salt bridge. Could you explain exactly what you have done and measured ? And what is a "Group 1 chlorine salt" ? Is it not a mistake ? Is it not "chloride" that you like to mention ?

Comment: @Maurice I believe Group 1 chlorine salt is Alkali metal chlorine salt eg NaCl, KCl etc. The voltage is probably decreasing as the mobility of the ions in salt bridge increases i.e. $\ce{K+}$ has more mobility than $\ce{Li+}$